# Can't connect to mongodb atlas nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to connect to an atlas DB using `mongoose`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const my_db =
    'mongodb+srv://adminUser:admisPassword@impact-9hs0w.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose
    .connect(my_db, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
            console.log('listening... ');
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

but it stays `[nodemon] starting 'node app.js'` for a while then it gives this log message

> Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT impact-9hs0w.mongodb.net
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19) {   errno: undefined,   code: 'ETIMEOUT',   syscall: 'queryTxt',
>   hostname: 'impact-9hs0w.mongodb.net' }

I whitelisted all IPs but it still won't connect

Comment: put your `const server` line after `catch` block

Comment: I did that so I only start my server if i connect with the db

Comment: check your `username` and `password` as well is it `adminUser` or only `admin` ?

Comment: i tried with the default user they gave me ,didn't work so i created my own ... still the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting support they told me to use the legacy connection link as so [Using the legacy link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUuF1.png)

Comment: Got my head spinning for 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your roles and passwords are set correctly in the link, for me the admin user just wasn't working, so I made a new one and it fixed my issue.